# Stop scroll-binded function until AJAX request has succeded

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, semaphore

I'm doing an infinite-scrolling script in jQuery that looks like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50){

    // If we have not loaded all pages yet
    if($('#feed').data('pagesloaded') != 0){
      var toload = $('#feed').data('pagesloaded') + 1;

      $.post("/feed/" + toload, { 'ignore': showed_posts_id }, function(html){
        if(html){
          $('#feed')
            .data('pagesloaded', toload)
            .append(html);
        }else{
          // If all pages are loaded, disable infinite scrolling
          $('#feed').data('pagesloaded', 0);
        }
      });

    }
  }
});
```

where `50` is the pixel offset from the bottom at which the event is triggered. However, when scrolling to the bottom of the page, the function gets triggered many times as the offset goes from 50 to 0, which causes all the pages to load at once.

I've heard of the technique that consists in binding events to $(window).ajaxStart() and .ajaxStop(), but as a lot of asynchronous ajax is going on in my application, it would interfere with the infinite scrolling. This is what I'm talking about:

```
var ajaxRunning = false;
$(window).ajaxStart(function () {
  ajaxRunning = true;
}).ajaxStop(function () {
  ajaxRunning = false;
});
```

I've thought of putting a simple binary semaphore that checks if a $.post is still going on, but I'm wondering if it's bad practice. What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I have finally done it by putting a simple data flag on $(window). If somebody thinks it's bad practive and knows a more effective way of doing it, I'd be glad to hear it!

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($('#feed').data('pagesloaded') != 0 && !$(window).data('infinite-scroll-async')){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50){

      // Locks the function
      $(window).data('infinite-scroll-async', true);

      var toload = $('#feed').data('pagesloaded') + 1;

      $.post("/feed/" + toload, { 'ignore': showed_posts_id }, function(html){

        if(html){
          $('#feed')
            .data('pagesloaded', toload)
            .append(html);
        }else{
          // If all pages are loaded, disable infinite scrolling
          $('#feed').data('pagesloaded', 0);
        }

      }).complete(function(){

        // Unlocks the function
        $(window).data('infinite-scroll-async', false);

      });

    }
  }
});
```